# How to get dropdown(mat-select) selected item text in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown and I want to get selected item text so here  `stat.REGION_NAME` and not the value in typescript. I used `selectionChange`, but getting value only not the item text.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Link Region Code</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Link Regions" name="linkregion" [(ngModel)]="linkregion" (selectionChange)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let stat of asyncLinkRegion" [value]="stat.REGION_CODE_MW">
      {{ stat.REGION_NAME }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Type script file

```
asyncLinkRegion: Observable<any>;


selected(value) {
  console.log('value is ='+value);
  console.log(value.resultText);
}
```

Comment: How about finding the region according to the region code?

Comment: means?i did not get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set object to `value`. So you can easily get all member of object. But at bigger object this will be overkill.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Link Region Code</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Link Regions" name="linkregion" [(ngModel)]="linkregion" (selectionChange)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let stat of asyncLinkRegion" [value]="stat">
      {{ stat.REGION_NAME }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your ts :

```
selected(change: MatSelectChange) {
  console.log(change.value.REGION_NAME);
}
```

Comment: MatSelectChange could not find in my angular

Comment: import ```MatSelectChange``` from ```@angular/material```.

Comment: i am getting undefined

Answer (score 1):

You already get the `REGION_CODE_MW` as `value` as the argument to your `selected` method. You could use the `find` method on the `asyncLinkRegion` array to get the `selectedRegion` by that `value` and then use the `REGION_NAME` property on it.

Here's how:

```
selected({ value }: any) {
  const selectedRegion = this.asyncLinkRegion.find(
    region => region.REGION_CODE_MW === value
  );

  selectedRegion &&
    console.log('Selected Region is: ', selectedRegion.REGION_NAME);
}
```

Alternatively, you could also set the `value`directly as `REGION_NAME` in your template:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Async Link Region Code</mat-label>
  <mat-select
    placeholder="Select Link Regions"
    name="linkregion"
    [(ngModel)]="linkregion"
    (selectionChange)="selectedWithAsync($event)"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let stat of (asyncLinkRegion$ | async)"
      [value]="stat.REGION_NAME"
    >
      {{ stat.REGION_NAME }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then you'll directly get the name of the selected region as value:

```
selectedWithAsync({ value }: any) {
  console.log('Got the selected value as: ', value);
}
```

Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-label-by-value?file=src/app/select-error-state-matcher-example.ts)** for your ref.

> NOTE: Check the below form field for the example.

Comment: asyncLinkRegion is  asyncLinkRegion: Observable<any>; ,so could not see  find method

Comment: Hah! If it's an `Observable<>` how are you able to use it without the `async` pipe in your template?

Comment: @peter check if the updated answer helps.

Comment: i need dropdown value and text  both to pass to web api through typescript

Comment: @peter `[value]="stat"`. Check the StackBlitz sample. It's updated.